# display random image and link per cookie or per session?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to make a way that i can show 5 images from a selection of about 100 images in a folder each time there is a new cookie set or each time the user logs in and out. I have already tried using javascript to display a different image based on the day of the week, however what i really want is a way to show 5 images at once with attached links that will change each time the user logs in and out? can someone point me in the write direction, i am new to php so even the smallest example of code would be helpful thank you.

Heres my javascript code that shows images based on the day, i dont know if this could prove helpful?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var now = new Date ();
var day = now.getDay();
//the week begins on SUNDAY
if(day == 0) document.write("<p><a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad0.png' alt='sunday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a></p><p><a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad0.png' alt='sunday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a></p>");
if(day == 1) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad1.png' alt='monday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
if(day == 2) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad2.png' alt='tuesday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
if(day == 3) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad3.png' alt='wednesday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
if(day == 4) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad4.png' alt='thursday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
if(day == 5) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad5.png' alt='friday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
if(day == 6) document.write("<a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='../PTB1/data/adverts/ad6.png' alt='saturday' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show 5 random images from a set of known images, this is the best way

```
$imagepool=array('path1.jpg','path2.jpg', ..... ,'path100.jpg');
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
  $randid=floor(rand(0,100));
  echo '<a href="#"><img src="'.$imagepool[$randid].'"></a>';
}
```

Or, if you have that naming scheme on all those images and they are in order, you don't have to define the list of images:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
  $randid=floor(rand(0,100));
  echo '<a href="#"><img src="/path/to/image_'.$randid.'.jpg"></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var now = new Date ();
var day = now.getDay();
var images = new Array(7);
var weekday=new Array(7);
images[0] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad0.png';
images[1] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad1.png';
images[2] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad2.png';
images[3] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad3.png';
images[4] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad4.png';
images[5] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad5.png';
images[6] = '../PTB1/data/adverts/ad6.png';
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";
document.write("<p><a href='YOUR-LINK-HERE'><img src='"+images[day]+"' alt='"+weekday[day]+"' width='180' height='180' border='0'></a></p>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish the five links/images in PHP too, using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
<?php
$today = strtotime("today");
$today = date('w',$today);
if ($today==0) echo '<a...><img.../></a>';
if ($today==1) echo '<a...><img.../></a>';
//etc...
```

If you want it random, I'm sure you can set a [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) variable in PHP upon login that would hold five images as variables.  If they log out and log in again, the variables would change and you would have five new images/links (whatever you're looking for).

Here's what you could do. Create a php file of variables, and a php file for handling logins:

```
<?php
    //variables page
    $your_link_array = array("GOOGLE" => "http://www.google.com","Stackoverflow" => "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "Youtube" => "http://www.youtube.com"); //three as an example, but you should make a lot if you want to pull five each time.
    ?>

    <?php 
    //log in page

    if($login=='success'){ //check username/password etc.
      session_start(); //log in successful
      $_SESSION['links'] = array_rand($your_link_array, 5); //pull 5 random variables from your array of links
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    //any other page that has session_start() at the beginning:
    session_start()
    foreach($_SESSION['links'] as $k => $v){ // show the five random links
      echo '<a href="'.$k.'" />'.$v.'</a>';
    } 
    ?>
```

Other resources: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)